# Limit of the amount of content that can be stuffed in an Object Parameter

Tags: java, html, applet

Is there a limit as to the amount of information that can be stuffed into a Value attribute for an param (inside of an Object)?

```
<object ...>
    <PARAM NAME="value_to_use" VALUE="[How much can be stuffed in here]">
</object>
```

I'm looking at seeing what is the max that an Java Applet can take in from a Parameter.

Comment: I would say probably a huge amount that's operating system specific

Comment: I'm figuring that its browser specific, I'm (mostly) looking for the smallest maximum of the browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe that there is a limit, it is just part of the HTML, and browsers can display huge HTML files.

Comment: Surely you can't pass in 64mb worth of data through the param into the applet. [Yes thats a pain, and yes it can be deliever to the browser but what about the browser to the applet]

Comment: I bet you can. You just have to download the whole HTML file first. It will be incredibly laggy, and memory usage will skyrocket, but it will work.